# When looking at a list of questions, why is `code` not highlighted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

When looking at a list of questions (whether on the homepage, when browsing by tag, when searching etc.), all the code blocks in the excerpt are inlined. Fair enough.

However, having code mixed in with regular text is very confusing. Why isn't the code highlighted like `inline code`? [Like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733732/httpurlconnection-buffering-rather-than-streaming-despite-setting-chunked-stream):

[image: Excerpt without code formatting]

...versus:

[image: Excerpt with code formatting]

Comment: This has been a *huge* pet peeve of mine. I always assumed that it was just a technological limitation that would take a long time to fix.

Comment: I mainly assumed that Markdown was not used in lists of questions for caching and/or performance reasons. As to this not taking "a competent programmer more than 1/2 an hour to an hour to implement", may I remind you of the [Dunning–Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be great, it can often be confusing reading the excerpts without differentiation.  I sometimes have thought a question was poorly done, until I went into the question and saw the proper markdown.

The same style could also be applied to Tag Wiki excerpts, so that some emphasis could be done.